# Passing to pointer to char in function and read value in caller

Tags: c++, c

I want to pass pointer to a function which pass this pointer to another function which points to the array and after this function end I want read the value in the caller function.

So this is the example code how I want it to work:

```
void fun_1(const char *data)
{
  /* some code */
  fun_2(data);
}

void fun_2(const char *data)
{
  /* some code */
  fun_3(data);
}

static bool fun_3(const char *data)
{
  static char buffer[20];
  /* some code */
  data = buffer;
  return true;
}
```

And to function fun_1 I want pass static char *resp and after fun_3 end I want to have address of buffer and then read out from it but now when fun_3 ends the resp is always NULL.

Comment: Assigning to a (non-reference) parameter has no effect outside the function - there is nothing special about pointers. You need to use the same method as if you wanted to modify an `int`.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. You'll need to ask a specific question as this isn't just a place where you can request people to write code for you. What do *you* think is wrong with your code? If you want to modify a pointer within a function, you'll need to pass it a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @Pam ...or a reference to a pointer (which would look like e.g.: `void fun_1(const char *&data)`). In C++, I would prefer the reference.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages with different solutions to this problem. Which language are you asking for?

Answer (score 2):

C is pass by value. Assigning to a local variable inside a function is transient, the effect will not pass to the caller’s parameter variable.

In your case I suspect you don’t want to use assignment but rather `strcpy` or `memcpy` to *copy* the buffer into a buffer provided by the calling code.

Be careful that the calling code allocates a sufficiently large buffer though, and make the caller pass in the buffer size to avoid overriding the available space:

```
static bool fun_3(const char *data, size_t size) {
  char buffer[20];
  if (size < sizeof buffer) return false;

  /* some code */
  memcpy(data, buffer, sizeof buffer);
  return true;
}
```

```
char buffer[25];
bool success = fun_3(buffer, sizeof buffer);
```

Alternatively, if you *really* want to return a pointer to a local static variable (but think carefully about the implications! In particular thread safety), you can either

- return the pointer:

  ```
  char *fun_3() {
    static char buffer[20];
    /* some code */
    return buffer;
  }
  ```

  ```
  char *buffer = fun_3();
  ```
- pass by pointer:

  ```
  static bool fun_3(const char **data) {
    static char buffer[20];
    /* some code */
    *data = buffer;
    return true;
  }
  ```

  ```
  char* buffer;
  bool result = fun_3(&buffer);
  ```

Comment: Since the question is tagged as c++, one could also mention pass by reference.

Comment: @churill Honestly, I’d rather not: I known it’s common but in most cases it’s bad API design. Limit returning data via the return value and leave parameters for input, unless there are overwhelming performance concerns.